# Unable to convert sklearn's bunch object into Pandas series object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here's the code I've been working on.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
housing = load_boston()
housing = pd.DataFrame(housing.data, columns = housing.feature_names)
housing['target'] = pd.Series(housing.target)
```

The error description is as follows

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-db1e02afaf46> in <module>()
 12 
 13 housing = pd.DataFrame(housing.data, columns = housing.feature_names)
---> 14 housing['target'] = pd.Series(housing.target)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in     __getattr__(self, name)
   4370             if  self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4371                 return self[name]
-> 4372             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
4373 
4374     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
```

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'target'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening since you named the `pd.DataFrame` exactly the same as your dataset, so that in `housing.target`, `housing` refers to the `DataFrame` instead of the dataset. Change it to something like

```
housing = load_boston()
housing_df = pd.DataFrame(housing.data, columns = housing.feature_names)
housing_df['target'] = pd.Series(housing.target)
```

and you're good.